# BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression Returning null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Ive adjusted a bound ViewModel, lets call it `MyViewModel` to inherit from `DependencyObject` and switched one of my normal CLR properties, lets call it `Name`, which used to fire `NotifyPropertyChanged()` inside the setter, to be a `DependencyProperty`.

`Name` is a two-way binding to a `TextBox` and is working fine.

However, calling `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(InstantiatedMyViewModel, MyViewModel.NameProperty)` always returns null.

1 - Is this because it is not possible to Pass my ViewModel (`InstantiatedMyViewModel`)in as the first parameter (rather than the instance of the textbox)? I assume that since it's a two-way binding, both the `InstantiatedMyViewModel`and the `TextBox` should have some binding knowledge

2 - If it is possible, are there any gotchas im missing?

It's working really well, but when I try to call

Comment: "I assume that since it's a two-way binding, both the InstantiatedMyViewModeland the TextBox should have some binding knowledge". That assumption is wrong. You can't get a binding expression from the source of a binding, only from the target, even if it's two-way.

Comment: Just an FYI, it is generally preferred that your ViewModels implement the INPC interface instead of inheriting from `DependencyObject`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
  var name = InstantiatedMyViewModel.GetValue(MyViewModel.NameProperty)
```

`BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` is used on a control that has a binding to some other object. e.g.

```
  <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Then

```
  var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(
     textBox1, TextBox.TextProperty);

  // "Name"
  var path = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path;
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you defined the binding in XAML on the `TextBox` - in that case the text box is the target of the binding, and your view model is the source - there's always a target and a source, and `BindingMode.TwoWay` only means that the value is updated both ways. Having said that you should know that only the target of the binding has information regarding binding expression.

From [BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN:

> Returns the BindingExpression object associated with the specified
>   binding target property on the specified object.